# DIY Powdered Biodegradable Soap

Tags: cleaning

I love Dr. Bronners unscented liquid soap! I can use it as dish washing liquid, body wash, laundry detergent, and shaving soap. And it's biodegradable so I can use it on the trail when backpacking! It makes my life VERY efficient by only needing to purchase one big container of this stuff.

Now I'm wondering if there is any powdered version of this kind of soap that is easily dissolvable in water and is accessible in major stores (I know Dr. Bronner's does not make any). If this is not the case, perhaps there is a very easy method to make some without having follow a bunch of steps?

Please let me know. Thanks!